# merge rows into groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which is constructed like this

```
age  share
...
 19   0.02
 20   0.01
 21   0.03
 22   0.04
...
```

I want to merge each age group into larger cohorts like `<20, 20-24, 25-29, 30-34, >=35` (and sum the shares).

Of course this could be easily done by hand, but I hardly can believe there is no dedicated function for that. However, I am not able to find this function. Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at `?cut` function, it does what you're looking for ;)

Comment: @Jilber thank you - I tried cut but I don't know how to handle the share column...

Comment: you should use cut2 in that case , i believe its in hmisc package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963508/generate-bins-from-a-data-frame -- check this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to use is [?cut](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html).  For example:

```
> myData <- read.table(text="age  share
+  19   0.02
+  20   0.01
+  21   0.03
+  22   0.04", header=TRUE)
> 
> myData$ageRange <- cut(myData$age, breaks=c(0, 20, 24, 29, 34, 35, 100))
> myData
  age share ageRange
1  19  0.02   (0,20]
2  20  0.01   (0,20]
3  21  0.03  (20,24]
4  22  0.04  (20,24]
```

Notice that you need to include breakpoints that are below the bottom number and above the top number in order for those intervals to form properly.  Notice further that the breakpoint is *exactly* (e.g.) `20`, and not `<=20, >=21`; that is, there cannot be a 'gap' between `20` and `21` such that `20.5` would be left out.

From there, if you want the `share`s in rows categorized under the same `ageRange` to be summed, you can create a new data frame:

```
> newData <- aggregate(share~ageRange, myData, sum)
> newData
  ageRange share
1   (0,20]  0.03
2  (20,24]  0.07
```

Comment: ok, that works. However, how is the actual merging done? so that rows 1 & 2 and also 3 & 4 are merged to one row? Hope this is no stupid question...

Comment: I'm sure it isn't a stupid question; unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean. Can you update your question to show what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I think I got it: `aggregate(share ~ ageRange, myData, sum)` - would you add this to your answer?