# How can I compute statistics by decile groups in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, quantile

I have a data.table and would like to compute stats by groups.

```
R) set.seed(1)
R) DT=data.table(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100))
```

Those groups should be defined by

```
R) quantile(DT$a,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1))
           10%            20%            30%            40%            50%            60%            70%            80%            90% 
-1.05265747329 -0.61386923071 -0.37534201964 -0.07670312896  0.11390916079  0.37707993057  0.58121734252  0.77125359976  1.18106507751
```

How can I compute say the average of `b` per bin, say if `b=-.5` I am within `[-0.61386923071,-0.37534201964]` so in bin `3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about :

```
> DT[, mean(b), keyby=cut(a,quantile(a,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1)))]
                cut          V1
1:               NA -0.31359818
2:   (-1.05,-0.614] -0.14103182
3:  (-0.614,-0.375] -0.33474492
4: (-0.375,-0.0767]  0.20827735
5:  (-0.0767,0.114]  0.14890251
6:    (0.114,0.377]  0.16685304
7:    (0.377,0.581]  0.07086979
8:    (0.581,0.771]  0.17950572
9:     (0.771,1.18] -0.04951607
```

To have a look at that NA (and to check the results anyway), I next did :

```
> DT[, list(mean(b),.N,list(a)), keyby=cut(a,quantile(a,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1)))]
                cut          V1  N                                                                                                                      V3
1:               NA -0.31359818 20                1.59528080213779,1.51178116845085,-2.2146998871775,-1.98935169586337,-1.47075238389927,1.35867955152904,
2:   (-1.05,-0.614] -0.14103182 10        -0.626453810742332,-0.835628612410047,-0.820468384118015,-0.621240580541804,-0.68875569454952,-0.70749515696212,
3:  (-0.614,-0.375] -0.33474492 10        -0.47815005510862,-0.41499456329968,-0.394289953710349,-0.612026393250771,-0.443291873218433,-0.589520946188072,
4: (-0.375,-0.0767]  0.20827735 10      -0.305388387156356,-0.155795506705329,-0.102787727342996,-0.164523596253587,-0.253361680136508,-0.112346212150228,
5:  (-0.0767,0.114]  0.14890251 10 -0.0449336090152309,-0.0161902630989461,0.0745649833651906,-0.0561287395290008,-0.0538050405829051,-0.0593133967111857,
6:    (0.114,0.377]  0.16685304 10             0.183643324222082,0.329507771815361,0.36458196213683,0.341119691424425,0.188792299514343,0.153253338211898,
7:    (0.377,0.581]  0.07086979 10            0.487429052428485,0.575781351653492,0.389843236411431,0.417941560199702,0.387671611559369,0.556663198673657,
8:    (0.581,0.771]  0.17950572 10             0.738324705129217,0.593901321217509,0.61982574789471,0.763175748457544,0.696963375404737,0.768532924515416,
9:     (0.771,1.18] -0.04951607 10              1.12493091814311,0.943836210685299,0.821221195098089,0.918977371608218,0.782136300731067,1.10002537198388,
```

Aside: I've returned a `list` column (each cell is itself a vector) there to have a quick look at the values going into the bins, just to check. `data.table` displays commas when printing (and shows just the first 6 items per cell), but each cell of `V3` there is actually a numeric vector.

So the values outside the first and last `break` are being coded together as NA. It's not obvious to me how to tell `cut` not to do that. So I just added -Inf and +Inf :

```
> DT[,list(mean(b),.N),keyby=cut(a,c(-Inf,quantile(a,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1)),+Inf))]
                 cut          V1  N
 1:     (-Inf,-1.05] -0.16938368 10
 2:   (-1.05,-0.614] -0.14103182 10
 3:  (-0.614,-0.375] -0.33474492 10
 4: (-0.375,-0.0767]  0.20827735 10
 5:  (-0.0767,0.114]  0.14890251 10
 6:    (0.114,0.377]  0.16685304 10
 7:    (0.377,0.581]  0.07086979 10
 8:    (0.581,0.771]  0.17950572 10
 9:     (0.771,1.18] -0.04951607 10
10:      (1.18, Inf] -0.45781268 10
```

That's better.  Or alternatively :

```
> DT[, list(mean(b),.N), keyby=cut(a,quantile(a,probs=seq(0,1,.1)),include=TRUE)]
                 cut          V1  N
 1:    [-2.21,-1.05] -0.16938368 10
 2:   (-1.05,-0.614] -0.14103182 10
 3:  (-0.614,-0.375] -0.33474492 10
 4: (-0.375,-0.0767]  0.20827735 10
 5:  (-0.0767,0.114]  0.14890251 10
 6:    (0.114,0.377]  0.16685304 10
 7:    (0.377,0.581]  0.07086979 10
 8:    (0.581,0.771]  0.17950572 10
 9:     (0.771,1.18] -0.04951607 10
10:       (1.18,2.4] -0.45781268 10
```

That way you see what the min and max is, rather than it displaying -Inf and +Inf.  Notice you need to pass `include=TRUE` to `cut` otherwise 11 bins will be returned with only 1 in the first.

Comment: I was missing that cut command ! Cool that's perfect... and I've never used keyby either

Comment: Why do you use `keyby` and not `by` here?

Comment: @hadley To sort the bins. `by=` returns the groups according to first appearance order.

Comment: @MattDowle When I run `DT[, list(mean(b),.N,list(a)), keyby=cut(a,quantile(a,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1)))]` I get `Error in setkeyv(ans, names(ans)[seq_along(byval)])` `Item 4 of list is not a vector`.  However the other 3 commands work fine.  If I run `DT[, list(mean(b),.N,paste0(as.character(a),collapse=",")), keyby=cut(a,quantile(a,probs=seq(.1,.9,.1)))]` then that works.  I'm running DT 1.9.2 on R3.0.1 Win7.  Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

I do this type of thing a lot, so I wrote a pretty flexible [bin_data()](https://github.com/ben519/mltools/blob/master/R/bin_data.R) method for it in my R package - [mltools](https://github.com/ben519/mltools). It's entirely `data.table` based and makes use of the new [non-equi joins](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable).

To answer your specific question, set Bin1 as a column in `DT`, then group by Bin1

```
library(data.table)
library(mltools)

DT[, Bin1 := bin_data(vals=a, bins=seq(.1, .9, .1), binType="quantile")]
DT[, list(mean(b)), keyby=Bin1]

                                        Bin1          V1
1:                                        NA -0.31359818
2:   [-1.05265747329296, -0.613869230708978) -0.14103182
3:  [-0.613869230708978, -0.375342019639661) -0.33474492
4: [-0.375342019639661, -0.0767031289639095)  0.20827735
5:  [-0.0767031289639095, 0.113909160788544)  0.14890251
6:    [0.113909160788544, 0.377079930573521)  0.16685304
7:    [0.377079930573521, 0.581217342522697)  0.07086979
8:    [0.581217342522697, 0.771253599758546)  0.17950572
9:      [0.771253599758546, 1.1810650775142] -0.04951607
```

---

## You can do other cool stuff too

**Make 10 equally-spaced bins by quantile**

```
DT[, Bin2 := bin_data(vals=a, bins=10, binType="quantile")]
DT[, list(mean(b)), keyby=Bin2]

                                         Bin2          V1
 1:     [-2.2146998871775, -1.05265747329296) -0.16938368
 2:   [-1.05265747329296, -0.613869230708978) -0.14103182
 3:  [-0.613869230708978, -0.375342019639661) -0.33474492
 4: [-0.375342019639661, -0.0767031289639095)  0.20827735
 5:  [-0.0767031289639095, 0.113909160788544)  0.14890251
 6:    [0.113909160788544, 0.377079930573521)  0.16685304
 7:    [0.377079930573521, 0.581217342522697)  0.07086979
 8:    [0.581217342522697, 0.771253599758546)  0.17950572
 9:      [0.771253599758546, 1.1810650775142) -0.04951607
10:       [1.1810650775142, 2.40161776050478] -0.45781268
```

**Make the last boundary left-closed right-open**

```
DT[, Bin3 := bin_data(vals=a, bins=10, binType="quantile", boundaryType="lcro)")]  
DT[, list(mean(b)), keyby=Bin2]

 1:                                        NA  0.42510038
 2:     [-2.2146998871775, -1.05265747329296) -0.16938368
 3:   [-1.05265747329296, -0.613869230708978) -0.14103182
 4:  [-0.613869230708978, -0.375342019639661) -0.33474492
 5: [-0.375342019639661, -0.0767031289639095)  0.20827735
 6:  [-0.0767031289639095, 0.113909160788544)  0.14890251
 7:    [0.113909160788544, 0.377079930573521)  0.16685304
 8:    [0.377079930573521, 0.581217342522697)  0.07086979
 9:    [0.581217342522697, 0.771253599758546)  0.17950572
10:      [0.771253599758546, 1.1810650775142) -0.04951607
11:       [1.1810650775142, 2.40161776050478) -0.55591413
```

**Specify your own explicit bins (notice empty bins are returned)**

```
bin_data(dt=DT, binCol="a", bins=seq(-5, 5, 1), returnDT=TRUE)

          Bin         a           b
  1: [-5, -4)        NA          NA
  2: [-4, -3)        NA          NA
  3: [-3, -2) -2.214700 -0.65069635
  4: [-2, -1) -1.989352 -0.17955653
  5: [-2, -1) -1.470752 -0.03763417
 ---                               
100:   [1, 2)  1.586833 -1.20808279
101:   [2, 3)  2.401618  0.42510038
102:   [2, 3)  2.172612  0.20753834
103:   [3, 4)        NA          NA
104:   [4, 5]        NA          NA
```

**Use variable size bins**

```
bin_data(dt=DT, binCol="a", bins=data.table(LB=c(-5, 0, 1), RB=c(0, 1, Inf)), returnDT=TRUE)

          Bin            a           b
  1:  [-5, 0) -0.626453811 -0.62036668
  2:  [-5, 0) -0.835628612 -0.91092165
  3:  [-5, 0) -0.820468384  1.76728727
  4:  [-5, 0) -0.305388387  1.68217608
  5:  [-5, 0) -0.621240581  1.43228224
 ---                               
 95: [1, Inf]  2.172611670  0.20753834
 96: [1, Inf]  1.178086997  0.21992480
 97: [1, Inf]  1.063099837  1.46458731
 98: [1, Inf]  1.207867806  0.40201178
 99: [1, Inf]  1.160402616 -0.73174817
100: [1, Inf]  1.586833455 -1.20808279
          Bin            a           b
```

Comment: Thanks @statquant I built it to solve a need that kept coming up again and again.  Please note that it needs some parameter checking and error handling, but as long as you feed it decent input, it'll work.

Comment: I'll use it and come back with suggestions/improvements,,,Typically I'll add a by so you can subset by, then do the bining (I do that all the time for like 2014,2015,...)

Comment: @ben. looks interesting. I will have a look at ```mltools```